# If you create an application, is it guaranteed that it will work to all API Levels?

Tags: android

I am wondering if that if I only test this application in this version of API, will it work still the same as API versions above? If it doesn't, what's a good way to develop an application? Create it 1 by 1 for each API?

I heard from my friend that he developed his app in KitKat but when he tested it in Marshmallow, some features are not working right.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, an welcome to software development. There is no easy answer to this. It depends what changes in the api. Often they try to keep things compatible, but not always. As new API's come out, you will need to adapt your code to deal with new interfaces, and ideally allow for both at the same time. Have fun

Answer (score 2):

My friend also met a problem similar to your friend's. His app runs well in kitkat but when he use Lollipop, the camera cannot work. There is nothing absolute, you can only test your app on as many devices as possible.

For some deprecated methods, you should keep an eye on them to make sure they can still work on higher sdk levels.

Something even more annoying is that some manufactures change the API so that they can customize the OS deeper such as Xiaomi MIUI.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such guarantee. You should pay attention every time a new major android version is released as it might affect your app, even if you're targetting a lower api level.

For example, Android O will limit background execution, even if you don't target api level 26. See: https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#atap

Answer (score 2):

Things are changing since every android update and here are a few of the many things which one should keep in mind while developing an application:

1. Runtime permissions are a major change in Marshmallow and onwards. Gone are the days when developers could add whatsoever permissions. Runtime permissions prompts the user to grant a permission to run a specific feature in the application and the user has an option of denying it. In case you haven't checked if your app has been granted the required permissions before conducting an operation  you will get a security exception.
2. Permission groups has been added. Each group has a set of permissions and one should check in which group your required permission falls before prompting for it.
3. Location services API has also undergone some changes. As per the old API the user would be taken to the settings page in order to turn on the location services. This has changed and now the user can be prompted to turn on the location services using the new API. Check documentation for more details.
4. Android O limits the number of background tasks which can be executed. So as a developer you have to be wise about which task is being executed in which thread.
5. App signing process has also changed significantly especially for application supporting marshmallow and above.

These are just a few of the things which one may keep in mind while developing an application. Also look out for deprecated api's.